# Liferay theme upgrade from 5.2 to 6.0?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I have upgraded my liferay 5.2 to 6.0 version with the default theme. Now I want to migrate my custom theme from 5.2 to liferay 6.0. What will be step that I can follow so that I can deploy and upgrade liferay 5.0 theme on liferay 6.0. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to deploy old theme on 6.0? What happened?

Comment: I want know how  to deploy old theme on 6.0. Simply I can copy and paste some folders to liferay 6.0 or something else I am not sure about this. Can you guide me how can I proceed from here ?

Comment: Which server do you use? Do you have packaged theme eg. war?

Comment: I am using Tomcat server. And I am not using WAR. Let me know if you want any further information so that it will be convenient for you to guide me from here.

Answer (score 1):

Sunil,

First thing you should try is unpacking your Plugins-SDK folder (which I believe you've already done judging by your LinkedIn post).

I normally have the following structure:

- code - This is my Plugins-SDK
- data
- deploy
- tomcat

Then you'll need to modify your ${PLUGINS-SDK}/build.${USERNAME}.properties file to point to your deploy directory.

The you can try copying your Liferay 5 theme folder to your plugins-sdk folder/themes/

Finally run ant clean deploy inside of the themes folder to deploy it.

~~ UPDATE ~~

See the "Writing your theme" section of this page: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Themes+v6.0

This explains about setting up a _diffs folder where you'll add your changes to the default theme. The contents of _diffs is then used to override the defaults.

Comment: +1, but it would probably be better to create new theme plugin and than copy/paste contents of old theme directory in it

Comment: I would totally agree with Martin. It's best to create a new theme with a new version of Liferay, and then apply your changes to that new theme.

Comment: Thanks Jonny and Martin for your guidance. I will check this solution and will post the update about the progress.

Comment: I have created blank theme that contains \docroot and build.xml. After this I have copied the respective folder from old 5.2.3 theme to newly created blank theme of liferay 6.0 .                                 New theme location is C:\liferay-portal-tomcat-6.0.6\liferay-portal-6.0.6\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.0.6\themes and after this I used "ant deploy" command. After selecting this theme from admin panel it is not showing properly. Can you suggest me what I can do for this issue?

Comment: Sunil, I've added an update to my answer. Let me know if you have any further questions. Also is your theme definitely deploying?